LSTM Prediction difficulties - Help Needed with Using Trained Model to Predict Future Flow Values
I have recently trained a predictive model using historical climate data from the file ClimateFlow_Data1950_2021_Daily_spider.xlsx, specifically focusing on the 'RCP26' sheet. My aim is to utilize this model to forecast Flow values using data from another file, RCPs_2025_2100.xlsx, with the target sheet being 'RCPs_2025_2100'.
To provide some context, the predictors in this scenario are Precipitation (PPT) and Maximum Temperature (Tmax), while the target variable I am seeking to predict is Flow.
However, I've encountered an issue: the Flow column in the second data file (RCPs_2025_2100.xlsx) is empty, and I need to fill it with the predicted values generated by my model.
How to proceed with this task? I'd greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions you might have.
df.head()
Out[6]: 
                 Date       PPT      Tmax  Flow
0 1950-01-01 12:00:00 -0.000092 -3.384451  58.0
1 1950-01-02 12:00:00  2.026306 -4.189279  61.2
2 1950-01-03 12:00:00 -0.000092 -2.875478  63.4
3 1950-01-04 12:00:00 -0.000092 -3.103854  49.0
4 1950-01-05 12:00:00  1.196228 -2.425506  60.9

df2=df = pd.read_excel('C:/LSTM_Python_Climate_streamflow/RCPs_2025_2100.xlsx', sheet_name='RCPs_2025_2100')

df2.head()
Out[8]: 
        Date   PPT  Tmax  Flow
0 2025-01-01  3.96 -0.87   NaN
1 2025-01-02  2.93 -2.05   NaN
2 2025-01-03  3.01 -1.32   NaN
3 2025-01-04  4.57 -1.67   NaN
4 2025-01-05  2.16 -1.89   NaN


import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_excel('C:/LSTM_Python_Climate_streamflow/ClimateFlow_Data1950_2021_Daily_spider.xlsx')

df.head()

# Drop rows with missing values

df.dropna(inplace=True)



#Find the correlation

import seaborn as sn

sn.heatmap(df.corr())



training_set = df.iloc[:26298, 1:5].values

test_set = df.iloc[26298:, 1:5].values



from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler



sc = MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (0,1))



training_set_scaled = sc.fit_transform(training_set)

test_set_scaled = sc.fit_transform(test_set)



test_set_scaled = test_set_scaled[:, 0:3]



X_train = []

y_train = []

WS = 24



for i in range(WS, len(training_set_scaled)):

    X_train.append(training_set_scaled[i-WS:i, 0:4])

    y_train.append(training_set_scaled[i,3])

   

X_train, y_train = np.array(X_train), np.array(y_train)



#X_train = np.reshape(X_train,(X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[3], 4))



X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]))

from keras.models import Sequential

from keras.layers import LSTM

from keras.layers import Dense

from keras.layers import Dropout

Model = Sequential()

Model.add(LSTM(units = 70, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], 4)))

Model.add(Dropout(0.2))

Model.add(LSTM(units = 70, return_sequences = True))

Model.add(Dropout(0.2))

Model.add(LSTM(units = 70, return_sequences = True))

Model.add(Dropout(0.2))

Model.add(LSTM(units = 70))

Model.add(Dropout(0.2))

Model.add(Dense(units = 1))

Model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error')

Model.fit(X_train,y_train, epochs = 5, batch_size = 32)



plt.plot(range(len(Model.history.history['loss'])), Model.history.history['loss'])

plt.xlabel('Epoch Number')

plt.ylabel('Loss')

plt.show()



Model.save('LSTM_ClimateChange_RCP85_24.h5')



from keras.models import load_model

Model = load_model('LSTM_ClimateChange_RCP85_24.h5')



prediction_test = []



Batch_one = training_set_scaled[-24:]

Batch_New = Batch_one.reshape((1,24,4))



for i in range(48):

    First_pred = Model.predict(Batch_New)[0]

    prediction_test.append(First_pred)   

    New_var = test_set_scaled[i,:]

    New_var = New_var.reshape(1,3)

    New_test = np.insert(New_var, 3, [First_pred], axis =1)   

    New_test = New_test.reshape(1,1,4)   

    Batch_New = np.append(Batch_New[:,1:,:], New_test, axis=1)

   

prediction_test = np.array(prediction_test)



SI = MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (0,3))

y_Scale = training_set[:,3:4]

SI.fit_transform(y_Scale)



predictions = SI.inverse_transform(prediction_test)

real_values = test_set[:, 3]



# Plot the first 100 values

plt.plot(real_values[:100], color='black', label='Actual Flow')

plt.plot(predictions[:100], color='blue', label='Predicted Flow')

plt.title('Humber River Flow Prediction')

plt.xlabel('Time (Day)')

plt.ylabel('Flow (M3/s)')

plt.legend()

plt.show()


#### Future data prediction from second data file

df2=df = pd.read_excel('C:/LSTM_Python_Climate_streamflow/RCPs_2025_2100.xlsx', sheet_name='RCPs_2025_2100')
df2.head()
df2.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
df2.index = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y.%m.%d')
df2.head()

print(df2.columns)

flow = df2['Flow']


def df_to_X_y(df2, window_size=5):
  df_as_np = df.to_numpy()
  X = []
  y = []
  for i in range(len(df_as_np)-window_size):
    row = [[a] for a in df_as_np[i:i+window_size]]
    X.append(row)
    label = df_as_np[i+window_size]
    y.append(label)
  return np.array(X), np.array(y)

WINDOW_SIZE = 5
X1, y1 = df_to_X_y(flow, WINDOW_SIZE)
X1.shape, y1.shape

X_pred, y_pred = X1[:20000], y1[:20000]

X_pred.shape, y_pred.shape, 

predictions = model1.predict(X_pred)


df2.index = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])


df2.drop(columns=['Date'], inplace=True)

def df_to_sequences(df2, window_size=5):
    sequences = []
    for i in range(len(df) - window_size):
        sequence = df.iloc[i:i + window_size]
        sequences.append(sequence)
    return sequences


sequences = df_to_sequences(df2)

X_new = np.array(sequences)

#X_new = X_new.reshape(X_new.shape[0], X_new.shape[1], X_new.shape[2])

predictions = model1.predict(X_new)

print("X_new shape:", X_new.shape)  # Debugging statement
predictions = model1.predict(X_new)




